# How to find a free patch of area in a tiled map?

Tags: algorithm, tiles, maps, tilemap

I've been trying to formulate the question and try to find some information on Google, but didn't managed to, so here it is...
We've got a nice tropic-themed game that is about to be released soon, that uses a tile map and an A* pathfinding is utilized and everything works flawlessly.

Until when it comes to the point where I need to somehow find **unoccupied patch of area** on the map that matches certain criteria, so that I can guide the player to place their just bought map objects on.

The map is 200x200 tiled map and it holds instances of each tile that determine two things - if it is occupied and if it is a water or a ground tile. These are already used for the A* pathfinding algorithm that I've put into the game.

Let's say the player buys a water-placible map object from the store and the map object occupies 5x5 tiles for instance. I need to guide the player to a free patch of water tiles where they can place that map object.

Any guidance and/or reference to such algorithms will be highly appreciated :) Thanks

**EDIT: It turns out that I need to find such a patch as close as possible to given point (centre of viewport for instance). This will improve user experience**

Comment: Will the objects all have rectangular areas, or will you also need to include irregularly shaped objects? And will you have objects that will be placeable partially on water, partially on land? I can think of an approach that would work for any situation, but it's a pretty brute-force approach, so it would help if you gave more specifics.

Comment: @Fault all the objects will have square areas, and there are no objects that are put partly on water and partly on land. I also have some suggestions but I wonder if there is definite algorithm for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**
Here's a fairly brute-force algorithm:

1. Scan across each row, left to right, top to bottom, until you hit an
   unoccupied tile of the correct type. (You can skip the far right columns/bottom rows once you get too close for the placement to fit)
2. Once you find a valid tile, check all tiles that would be within the placement footprint, if you put the top left corner here. Start with the tile furthest away (the bottom-right corner of the placement), and gradually work back.
3. If you find an invalid tile (wrong type/already
   occupied), mark all tiles in the rectangle containing your proposed top-left corner and the obstacle as "explored", and resume searching with the
   next tile after the proposed top-left corner.
4. As you continue your main scan, skip over any tiles marked "explored"
5. If your search in 2 does not find an obstacle, return your proposed top-left corner as a valid placement and terminate.

Steps 3 & 4 are a small improvement over straight-up brute force search, in that they keep you from repeatedly checking the same patch. Starting from the opposite corner lets you skip as many tiles as possible using this trick.

**Method 2**
If you need to improve on this (profile, to see if it's worth your trouble), you can keep a bit of helper data with each tile: the size of the largest unoccupied square of the same type with that tile as its top-left corner.

Fill this data in once during map generation, by brute force if need be, then update it any time a tile changes state (search a rectangle up & left of the changed tile for any tiles that count it in their largest square. Decrease their largest square so that it ends just before the changed tile. You can end this search early once you've gone as far as the widest placeable item in your game.)

Now you can find a rectangle of the right size with a linear scan of the map. You can shape this scan any way you want - say searching an expanding spiral out from the focus of the player's current view, so that you can minimize the camera move required.

If you need even faster lookups (doubtful), you can use this data to sort your tiles into a heap (or series of heaps) by largest-placeable-area. Then in a O(1) operation you can pluck out a tile big enough for a given placement, or correctly conclude that none exists. (Just watch out, if you always choose the biggest-available area, regardless of the size of the  placement, you'll tend to fritter away your wide open space on small placements)

That kind of acceleration structure can be expensive to maintain though, so only do it if your searches for placeable areas are causing noticeable problems.

Comment: immediate +1 for the extensive answer :) I need to implement this and will tell the results once I've got them. Thank you

Comment: it works and is blazingly fast. I didn't expect that really.. Thought it would be laggy - the map is 300x300 actually. And it finishes in a blink of an eye. Thank you, answer accepted!

Comment: Glad to hear it! It's pretty amazing how quickly modern chips can chew through data, even with a fairly blunt algorithm, isn't it? :) If I may ask, which method did you decide to use?

Comment: The first one. I have a dynamic isometric map where objects can be moved and release previous positions and occupy new. So I decided to first try the more straightforward method, and, if it is not fast enough, try optimizing it. Fortunately, it proved to be fast enough. There is a slight lag due to that, but it is almost unnoticeable.

Comment: I need some more help, I'd be very glad if you assist me. Thanks

Comment: Keeping an organized lists of areas of interest like suitable squares of different sizes and their positions is preferable since it would only take o(1). It would also be easy to find the nearest one that way..

Otherwise you need to iterate in an expanding spiral shape.

Comment: I think you can still use the same method, but chunk-wise. Say you divide your 300x300 map into 10x10 chunks of 30x30 tiles each. When you want to find a placement close to a given point, first search the chunk that contains that point (using method 1), then the next-closest chunk, etc. This doesn't guarantee you'll find the very closest spot, but if your chunks are smaller than your viewport then it should be close enough.

Comment: @DMGregory wouldn't that miss suitable patches if they're splat by two chunks?

Comment: Not necessarily. You limit your top-left-corner choices to the chunk in question, but you allow the right & bottom edges to extend into neighbouring chunks. If a viable patch exists, it will be found.

Comment: @DMGregory actually I came up with a more clever solution, because I didn't like the idea of extending into right and bottom edges. I extended every chunk with half of the length of the lookup area in each direction and made the chunk size dynamic in accordance to lookup area length (so that fewer tiles are iterated multiple times). Please add your last comment to the answer :) Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a good strategy. :)

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem is finding the largest square block in a binary matrix and the algorithm actually gives the number of largest square blocks for every cell if this cell is top-left of the square block.

A very good documentation of the algorithm is the answer by Joy Dutta in the [Dynamic programming - Largest square block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726632/dynamic-programming-largest-square-block) question on SO.